# `purrr::map` to any type

Tags: r, purrr

Is there a way to map to any type with `purrr::map`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data_frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                 val = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                 date = ymd("2017-01-01") + days(1:6))

df1 <- df %>% nest(-id) %>% 
  mutate(first_val = map_dbl(data, ~ .$val[1]), 
         first_day = map(data, ~ .$date[1]))
```

I would like `first_day` to be a column of type `<date>` as in `df`. I have tried `flatten`, but this does not work as it coerces the column to numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`purrr 1.0.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/12/purrr-1-0-0/#new-map_vec), you can use [`map_vec`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

> `map_vec()` (along with `map2_vec()`, and `pmap_vec()`) handles more
> types of vectors. `map_vec()` extends `map_lgl()`, `map_int()`,
> `map_dbl()`, and `map_chr()` to arbitrary types of vectors, like
> dates, factors, and date-times:

```r
df %>% nest(data = -id) %>% 
  mutate(first_val = map_dbl(data, ~ .$val[1]), 
         first_day = map_vec(data, ~ .$date[1]))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     id data             first_val first_day 
  <dbl> <list>               <dbl> <date>    
1     1 <tibble [3 × 2]>         1 2017-01-02
2     2 <tibble [3 × 2]>         1 2017-01-05
```

---

`map_vec` will always return a simpler vector with the correct vector class (erroring if there is no common type), but you can also specify it with `.ptype`:

```r
df %>% nest(data = -id) %>% 
  mutate(first_val = map_vec(data, ~ .$val[1], .ptype = integer()), 
         first_day = map_vec(data, ~ .$date[1], .ptype = Date()))
```

Answer (score 11):

`purrr` is type-stable and this takes some getting used to.

In this case, it returns a list where you expect a `<date>`.

A simple and "stable" solution to you case would be to replace the second `map` with a `map_dbl` and have the output turned back to a `<date>` object using `lubridate`'s `as_date`, like this:

```
df3 <- df %>% nest(-id) %>% 
   mutate(first_val = map_dbl(data, ~ .$val[1]), 
          first_day = as_date(map_dbl(data, ~ .$date[1])))
```

You get:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  id             data                 first_val  first_day
 <dbl>          <list>                  <dbl>     <date>
 1              <tibble [3 × 2]>         1      2017-01-02
 2              <tibble [3 × 2]>         1      2017-01-05
```

Which is what you wanted (for this example).

**EDIT**: for any other types (other than `<date>`) you would have to find a different solution, however, the standard types are covered by the dedicated `map_lgl`, `map_dbl`, `map_chr`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to the `map_dbl() %>% as_date()` is to use `unnest()` on the output column of interest:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

df <- data_frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                 val = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                 date = ymd("2017-01-01") + days(1:6))

df %>% nest(-id) %>% 
  mutate(first_val = map_dbl(data, ~ .$val[1]), 
         first_day = map(data, ~ .$date[1])) %>% 
  unnest(first_day)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>      id data             first_val first_day 
#>   <dbl> <list>               <dbl> <date>    
#> 1     1 <tibble [3 × 2]>         1 2017-01-02
#> 2     2 <tibble [3 × 2]>         1 2017-01-05
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on [purrr's `reduce()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html) with `c()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
             val = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
             date = ymd("2017-01-01") + days(1:6))

df1 <- df %>% nest(data = -id) %>% 
    mutate(first_val = map_dbl(data, ~ .$val[1]), 
           first_day = reduce(map(data, ~ .$date[1]), c))
```

Result:

```
> df1
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     id data             first_val first_day 
  <dbl> <list>               <dbl> <date>    
1     1 <tibble [3 × 2]>         1 2017-01-02
2     2 <tibble [3 × 2]>         1 2017-01-05
```